# Why can't i reset the vector?

Tags: c++

I want to zero vector 'is_node_visited' and set  vector "node_parent" on minus one but my function s don't work. I'm getting the following errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'to_false'
    to_false(is_node_visited, vertex_count);
    ^~~~~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<bool> [vertex_count]' to 'vector<bool> &' for 1st argument
void to_false(vector<bool>& T,int n)
     ^
error: no matching function for call to 'minus_one'
    minus_one(node_parent, vertex_count);
    ^~~~~~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<int> [vertex_count]' to 'vector<int> &' for 1st argument
void minus_one(vector<int>& T, int n)
     ^
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

void to_false(vector<bool>& T,int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) T[i] = false;
}

void minus_one(vector<int>& T, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) T[i] = -1;
}

int main()
{
  int vertex_count, edge_count,first_vertex, second_vertex, i;


  cin>>vertex_count;
  cin>>edge_count;
  vector <int> tab[vertex_count];
  vector <bool> is_node_visited[vertex_count];
  vector <int> node_parent[vertex_count];
  queue<int> Q;

    for(i=0; i<edge_count; i++)
    {
        cin>>first_vertex;
        cin>>second_vertex;
        tab[first_vertex].push_back(second_vertex);
        tab[second_vertex].push_back(first_vertex);
    }

    to_false(is_node_visited, vertex_count);
    minus_one(node_parent, vertex_count);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: is `is_node_visited` supposed to be an array of vectors or just a single vector?

Answer (score 1):

```
vector <bool> is_node_visited[vertex_count];
```

This is not a vector, it's an array of vectors, `[]` means array.

I think you meant this instead

```
vector <bool> is_node_visited(vertex_count);
```

That's a `vector<bool>` whose initial size is `vertex_count`.

Also this code

```
int vertex_count;
cin >> vertex_count;
vector <int> tab[vertex_count];
```

where I think you really do mean to have an array of vectors, is not legal C++. In C++ array sizes must be *compile time constants* but `vertex_count` is a variable.

You can have a vector of vectors.

```
int vertex_count;
cin >> vertex_count;
vector <vector <int>> tab(vertex_count);
```

That would be legal C++.

Comment: I need array, because 
 I want to write BFS

Comment: If you want an array, why did you write `to_false` with a vector?

Comment: And of course, you can write BFS with either an array or a vector. Just make your mind up which you want.

Comment: because one guy told me to change to a vector

Comment: Which of your vectors are we talking about?